# How do I avoid NullReferenceException when implementing operator==

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement `operator==` in one of my classes. According to the book *Microsoft Visual C# Step by Step* I should write it like so:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace EqualTest2
{
    public class EqualTestClass
    {
        public double _x1;

        public EqualTestClass(double x1)
        {
            _x1 = x1;
        }

        public override bool Equals(object other)
        {
            if (other is EqualTestClass)
            {
                return (Math.Abs(_x1 - ((EqualTestClass)other)._x1) < 1e-6);
            }
            return false;
        }

        public override int GetHashCode()
        {
            return base.GetHashCode();
        }

        public static bool operator ==(EqualTestClass lhs, EqualTestClass rhs)
        {
            return lhs.Equals(rhs);
        }

        public static bool operator !=(EqualTestClass lhs, EqualTestClass rhs)
        {
            return !lhs.Equals(rhs);
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            EqualTestClass test1 = new EqualTestClass(1.0);
            EqualTestClass test2 = new EqualTestClass(1.0);
            EqualTestClass test3 = new EqualTestClass(2.0);
            EqualTestClass test4 = null;

            Debug.WriteLine("1: {0}", test1 == test2);
            Debug.WriteLine("2: {0}", test1 == test3);
            Debug.WriteLine("3: {0}", test1 == test4);
            Debug.WriteLine("4: {0}", test4 == test1);
        }
    }
}
```

This program throws `NullReferenceException` on the fourth debug line because `lhs` is null on the line `lhs.Equals(rhs)`. I can't put `if (lhs != null)` in `operator==` because that causes infinite recursion (as the book warns). So in order to avoid an exception when comparing a null instance of my class, I changed the implementation to this:

```
    public static bool operator ==(EqualTestClass lhs, EqualTestClass rhs)
    {
        try
        {
            return lhs.Equals(rhs);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public static bool operator !=(EqualTestClass lhs, EqualTestClass rhs)
    {
        try
        {
            return !lhs.Equals(rhs);
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

(I'm new to C# coming from an Objective C background where `[lhs method:argument]` happily returns nil if `lhs` is nil so an exception like this would never happen.)

Is this exception-based implementation idiomatically correct C#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would avoid using a try-catch block for your case. You need only change your operators to this:

```
public static bool operator ==(EqualTestClass lhs, EqualTestClass rhs)
{
    return object.Equals(lhs, rhs);
}
public static bool operator !=(EqualTestClass lhs, EqualTestClass rhs)
{
    return !object.Equals(lhs, rhs);
}
```

This will do the null-checking for you while still calling your overridden `Equals()` method. According to the source code for `System.Object.Equals()`:

```
public static bool Equals(Object objA, Object objB) 
{
    if (objA==objB) {
        return true;
    }
    if (objA==null || objB==null) {
        return false;
    }
    return objA.Equals(objB);
}
```

Looks like that takes care of your issue.

Answer (score 4):

Consider using [ReferenceEquals(lhs, null)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals(v=vs.110).aspx)  to check the reference for null for each of your args before checking for equality

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the arguments by reference:

```
if (!ReferenceEquals(lhs, null)) ...
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply do a null test first

```
if(lhs == null || rhs == null){
```

And handle that the way you want. (return false, or maybe true if both null)

.equals() requires an object and will throw NullPointer if you try to call it on a null object. But == works fine.

Comment: that's the core of the problem: infinite recursion